# Reading all .txt files from a folder?

Tags: c

I am trying to read all .txt files which is in the directory named "dataset". All text files has name like 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt... And then saving the contents of the files to a structure named FILES.

I used the dirent.h library and readdir( ) function as I saw in some sources. But the file name which program read from directory does not return correctly. Here is my related code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

typedef struct FILES{
    char **words;
    int wordCount;
}FILES;

void readFiles();

FILES *files;
int fileCount;

int main(){
    readFiles();

    return 0;
}

void readFiles(){
    FILE *file;
    DIR *directory;
    struct dirent *filesInDirectory;
    int counter;

    fileCount = 1;
    files = (FILES *)malloc(sizeof(FILES));
    directory = opendir("dataset");
    if(directory == NULL){
        printf("Warning: The directory name that is given in the code is not 
valid ..!");
        return;
    }else{
        while((filesInDirectory = readdir(directory)) != NULL){
            printf("%s\n", filesInDirectory->d_name);
            file = fopen(filesInDirectory->d_name, "r+");
            if(file == NULL){
                printf("Warning: The file named %s could not open ..!", 
filesInDirectory->d_name);
                return;
            }
            files[fileCount-1].wordCount = 1;
            files[fileCount-1].words = (char **)malloc(files[fileCount-
1].wordCount * sizeof(char *));
            counter = 0;

            while(!feof(file)){
                files[fileCount-1].words[counter] = (char *)malloc(20 * 
sizeof(char));
                fscanf(file, "%s", files[fileCount-1].words[counter]);
                files[fileCount-1].wordCount++;
                files[fileCount-1].words = (char **)realloc(files[fileCount-
1].words, files[fileCount-1].wordCount * sizeof(char *));
                counter++;
            }
            fileCount++;            
            fclose(file);
        }
    }

}
```

The file name that I printed in here "printf("%s\n", filesInDirectory->d_name);" is ".". Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: `while(!feof(file)){` -- This is wrong - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, thank you for this. I will keep that in my mind. But do you have any idea why the file name does not returns correctly?

Comment: `readdir` will return directories - First one being `.` and the second `..`

Comment: Also casting `malloc` is bad - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @EdHeal I could not notice it. What can I use instead readdir to read .txt files or at least taking the names of its.

Comment: Check the returned filenames and check that they end in `.txt`

Comment: @EdHeal I am sorry, could not understand. Returned from which function? I did not know how to read files or at least file names in a directory.

Comment: Check that `filesInDirectory->d_name` ends in `.txt`! Use `strlen` and `strcmp`

Comment: @EdHeal filesInDirectory->d_name is just "."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER BUT TOO BIG FOR A COMMENT**

Here are your problems:

1.

```
 files = (FILES *)malloc(sizeof(FILES));
```

This is enough size of one `FILES`. This is will not be enough

2. After

   ```
   while((filesInDirectory = readdir(directory)) != NULL){
   ```

Put something like

```
size_t len = strlen(filesInDirectory->d_name);
if (len < 5 || strcmp(filesInDirectory->d_name + len - 4, ".txt") != 0) {
  continue;
}
```

This will check to ensure files end in .txt

3. Consider using `fstat` to ensure that the file is a text file
4. Remove the casts on malloc
5. Perhaps use `realloc` for `files`
6. `while ... feof` is bad - see link above
7. `fscanf(file, "%s",` - Buffer overruns is possible. Do something about this. Read the manual page